# Java JPanel doesnt get painted

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm coding a simple top-down-shooter and I'm trying to render the graphics the active way so the JPanel doesn't get repainted by the OS and I can control the repainting. 
I have a Level class which calls the render() with the x and y position and the BufferedImage of the level or entity in the Screen class (JPanel). My problem now is the the paintComponents() method in the Screen class never gets called. I have tried a couple of variants to fix the problem. I have also tried it with Canvas but either the entites started blinking or I got an Exception on createBufferStrategy(3). Anyway this is my source code now and I really don't know whats the problem now.

### EDIT

Here is the important part of the code which is not working, repaint doesn't call paintComponent...

```
public void render(){
    if(graphics != null){
        graphics.dispose();
    }
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(offScreen.getSubimage(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()), 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    offScreen.flush();
}

public void render(int x, int y, BufferedImage image) {
    graphics = offScreen.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
//  offScreenGraphics.dispose();
}
```

The problem is that paintComponent doesn't get called, repaint() calls nothing, the debugger just goes over it.

### Canvas attempt

This is my attempt with Canvas, the problem there is that I can't create a bufferStrategy in the outcommented code. In the other render method it's working but its useless there.

```
    public void render() {
//  if (buffer == null) {
//      createBufferStrategy(2);
//      buffer = getBufferStrategy();
//  }

    Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, null);
    if (g != null) {
        g.dispose();
    }
    if(!buffer.contentsLost()){
        buffer.show();
    }

}

public void render(int x, int y, BufferedImage image) {
    if (buffer == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        buffer = getBufferStrategy();
    }
    Graphics g = offScreen.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
}
```

I hope you can help me and thank you also for helping me.

If you have other improvements I would also like to hear about it.

Comment: You likely intended to override `paintComponent()`, rather than `paintComponents()`.

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through for what is probably a simple mistake. Consider providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In any case, don't use `Canvas`. You might need to call `repaint` in order to "force" a call of `paintComponent`.

Comment: Your off screen buffer should be the same size as you component. Instead of doing this the hard way, if you want complete control over the painting process, then you should consider using [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Comment: Alright I will try it with paintComponent(). @MadProgrammer how can I use BufferStrategy with JPanel? And would offScreen.getSubimage() also work?

Comment: You can't use `BufferStrategy` with `JPanel`, you MUST use `Canvas`, this removes the process out of Swing's painting process and provides you direct control over it

Comment: I have found the error -.-
I created a new Screen() instead of adding the screen created in the main method...
Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `render` method on the `JPanel` should only update state, and call for a [`repaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29). The painting will be done in [`paintComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) as a result of the call to `repaint`.